# How to add extra result with google map api autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Generally if we use Google map autocomplete it returns 5 rows. For example if we type **dfw** the google autocomplete will display the following output:
[image]

How can I add extra result with this Google map autocomplete result? I want to add extra row with the result. Expected output is given bellow:

[image]

I am using google map JavaScript API.
    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
            var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
            document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
    }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: geolocation,
                radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
    }
}
```

HTML is:

```
<input id="street_number" name="street_number" type="hidden" />
<input id="route" name="route" type="hidden" />
<input id="locality" name="locality" type="hidden" />
<input id="administrative_area_level_1" name="administrative_area_level_1" type="hidden" />
<input id="country" name="country" type="hidden" />
<input id="postal_code" name="postal_code" type="hidden" />
<input id="autocomplete" type="text" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="geolocate()" />
```

Comment: Do I understand you right that you want to include airports in your results? Or do you want to include custom data?

Comment: I want both. I can include airport or Custom address (home,office address saved in my database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google offers numerous place types for its places search. Here you find all [Place Types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?hl=en) which are available and here some information of how to [add places](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place?hl=en#add-place).

Comment: Thanks for you reference. But i don't want to add a new place to Google map. My place is already added. I just want to show another row in google autocomplete result.

Answer (score 1):

Us this..

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('MyAutocomplete'));
        setTimeout(function(){
                            $(".pac-container").append('<div id="areasearch" class="pac-item" onmousedown="alert(\'Yes, working\')"><span class="pac-icon icon-airport"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched"></span>Sample Address</span> <span>it\'s Working</span></div>');
                        }, 500);
```

Comment: Do not use this. Undocumented and ugly.

Comment: @Rashedul Alam Do you have any way to add that value at last?
It do the work , but add it on first index, I wanted to add that custom value at last index?